# Issue in full calendar first day option

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have configured my week start on Wednesday. I am setting cal date as jan 7(tuesday). now i am going to week view. Its shows the week date from 2nd jan to 8th jan. What I except is, for given date 7, its should choose week duration from jan 5(sunday) to jan 11. Please refer the screen shot and help me.

http://s30.postimg.org/epq10h2o1/edited.png

Comment: Please add some code. What you have tried? or share the fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3fL/15/

Answer (score 22):

Add first day to the calendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaList'
            },               
            firstDay: 0
 });
```

Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.

see --> http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/

Answer (score 0):

Moving to answer from the comments

If I comment your `firstDay: 3,` then the week is starting from the Sunday.

Will it work for you? If you configure your start day in a week as Wednesday then it will start from that day.

Comment: I want to start week on wednesday thats y i am configuring first day.
My question is if i set date as 7, it will choose one week. The week will starts on sunday to saturday default. so it will load 5 to 11. 
Now i am configuring first day as wednesday so the week needs to display from 8 to 14. but its showing 2 to 8.

Comment: If we configure first day as 0, it will be displayed from 6 to 12. Now i want to start from wednesday. so i am expecting this to start from 8 to 14. Thats it. Hope u understand.

Comment: Okey. Let me tell you how fullcalender works. Todays date is 7th Jan so by default it will show the week that contains the today's date, it does not matter what startdate you choose.

Comment: At least i need a hack like this, if u can help me.

Comment: If you want a hack like this the only way is to change inside the fullcalender plugin js files. Its a custom requirement no plugin will provide you support like this.